# Converting image to Black & White image on iPhone SDK issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, sdk

I've used a familiar code to convert image to Black & White which I've founded on several forums.
The code is:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSapce = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, originalImage.size.width,     originalImage.size.height, 8, originalImage.size.width, colorSapce, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height), [originalImage CGImage]);
CGImageRef bwImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSapce);

UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bwImage]; // This is result B/W image.
CGImageRelease(bwImage);

return resultImage;
```

When I'm using this code with on Horizontal image it's work fine,
but when I'm trying a to use this code on Vertical image, the result is
disproportionate image and rotate 90 degree left.

Can anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks,
Kfir.

Answer (score 1):

The UIImage can be rotated (check the imageOrientation property). When this is the case, the rotation has to be applied to the CGImage before rendering. Otherwise you get the result you are experiencing. The solution is to apply the correct transform to the CGContext before drawing the image. For example, the following code generates and applies such transform:

```
  // image is the original UIImage
   CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

   CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
   CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

   CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
   UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    // Do the drawing
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
```